# CentOS server cannot connect to external IPv4 sites

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I recently installed CentOS 6.5 on an old laptop I had, and I am currently using it alongside Samba as a backup server. The problem is, It cannot connect to other external services (outside my home network) using IPv4. For example, doing `wget 173.194.33.129` (Google's IPv4) returns a:

```
[root@nas ~]# wget 173.194.33.129
--2014-11-05 06:28:48--  http://173.194.33.129/
Connecting to 173.194.33.129:80... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

while doing `wget google.com` works just fine. I am able to ssh into the server via it's internal IP address (`192.168.1.xxx`).

Here is my `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`:

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=B8:88:E3:35:4A:A2
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=b063301b-a5e8-4eec-9dda-5bcba54a0163
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.1.103
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your netmask. You seem to be missing both **

> NETWORK=192.168.1.0
>
> NETMASK=255.255.255.0

Try reconfiguring the NIC. Install system-config-network & use it to reconfigure the NIC.

> yum install system-config-network
>
> root@host:~# system-config-network

**(I am assuming that you are using the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet)
Hope this was helpful. (^_^)